# Precision and accuracy in NDSolve and NMinimize

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

I use `NDSolve` quite a lot and have noticed that setting values for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` can greatly affect the solution outcome, and can also greatly increase the calculation time required to produce a solution. As such, I have a few questions:

1. If, for example, I set `AccuracyGoal -> 18` and `PrecisionGoal -> 10`, will this essentially make `AccuracyGoal -> 10` due to the limitation in possible decimal places available from the `PrecisionGoal` setting? Would there be a point in having different values of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` or is it best to set them to the same value?
2. Where does `WorkingPrecision` fit into the picture? What I usually do is just set `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` as high as possible without making the calculation time "unbearably" slow. When I try and use `WorkingPrecision` I always get and error saying `"The precision of the differential equation ... is less than WorkingPrecision ..."`, so tend to ignore its use.
3. If computation time is not an issue, what would be the best way to set `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`? Would they be set in such a way that you settle on a value once the `NDSolve` output solutions from various test values of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` start to converge?
4. I've noticed that when using `NMinimize` on the output `InterpolatingFunction` of an `NDSolve` solution,  setting values for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` in `NMinimize` doesn't seem to have an effect on the minimized value attained, and only seems to depend of what your `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` values were in `NDSolve` (although using low values of AG and PG in `NMinimize` does make a large difference). Is it pointless to set values for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` when using `NMinimize`?
5. And finally, I know this is a very broad question and most likely has many different ways of attacking the problem based on what you are doing, but are there any tricks or tips that may speed up `NDSolve` and `NMinimize` calculations without affecting accuracy too much? This is what I'm struggling with most at the moment.

EDIT:

6. Is there a way to see how much error has accumulated in your NDSolve output in order to see if you need to up the accuracy and/or precision settings? I see that Mathematica uses "Numerical Precision Tracking" (http://www.ordinate.de/wolfram/TechGuide/EN/technology/offlineguide/precisiontracking.html), could this somehow be used to show error accumulation?

Comment: 1. and 2. can be answered by a close reading of the [Advanced Documentation for `NDSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveIntroductoryTutorial.html#1076263921).

Comment: 3. I'd go with setting `AccuracyGoal` to `Infinity`, and tweak `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` as needed, with the latter setting being set slightly higher than the former.

Comment: 4. It's the same story with `N[2., 25]`: you can't ask for precision/accuracy higher than what your data has.

Comment: 5. The obvious tips: don't use a nonstiff method on a stiff problem, and if you have known constraints or good guesses for the optima, use them!

Comment: To 5.: Numerical methods do a lot of objective function evaluations, so it would be wise to speed up the computation time for evaluating the objective function. You might want to consider compiling it.

Comment: ...with the caveat that compiled functions can only return machine-precision output.

Comment: What is the reasoning for using `WorkingPrecision` when it is equivalent to using `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` in combination? If feel like I'm missing an important aspect about it. Unfortunately I'm still a little confused after reading the documentation. Would there be a point to using only `AccuracyGoal` by itself or `PrecisionGoal` by itself, or should they always be used in tandem?

Comment: `WorkingPrecision` means what it says: all the arithmetic under the hood is done with numbers whose precision is set to that. How the other two options are dealt with depends on the `N*[]` function under consideration.